# pyProj Coordinate Transformation Incorrect

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyproj

I'm using pyProj to transform extents between two different geographical systems. In a case when both my systems are the same I expect to get back the same extents as inputted but this isn't happening for the below mentioned case:

```
import pyproj
inProj = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:{0}".format(3857)) # Mercator
outProj = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:{0}".format(3857))
x =  (-20037507.0672, 20037509.6184)
y =  (-1467048.29156, 8625918.8737)
print pyproj.transform(inProj,outProj,x,y)
```

The output comes out to be : `((-20037507.0672, -20037507.067178484), (-1467048.2915600014, 8625918.873699998))`

Which is incorrect as my X-Coordinate extents are same for xMax and xMin.

If I change my co-ordinate systems

```
import pyproj
inProj = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:{0}".format(3857)) # Mercator
outProj = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:{0}".format(4326)) # WGS84
x =  (-20037507.0672, 20037509.6184)
y =  (-1467048.29156, 8625918.8737)
print pyproj.transform(inProj,outProj,x,y)
```

My X-coordinate output comes out to be : `(-179.99998854118687, -179.99998854099357)`

Which is again incorrect. Is this due to a domain issue in pyProj or is there any other reason ?

Answer (score 5):

You make a mistake with the [pyproj](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj) parameters

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj  = Proj("+init=EPSG:3857"))
outProj = Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")
x1,y1 =  (-20037507.0672, 20037509.6184)
x2,y2 =  (-1467048.29156, 8625918.8737)
# with the x,y coordinates of pointx
print transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
(-179.99998854118687, 85.08398750388278)
# with the x,y coordinates of point pointy
print transform(inProj,outProj,x2,y2)
(-13.178719028497799, 61.16289280460126)
```

Control with [GDAL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) ([Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook: Projections](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html))

```
from osgeo import osr
from_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
from_srs.ImportFromEPSG(3857)
to_srs =  osr.SpatialReference()
to_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
transf = osr.CoordinateTransformation(from_srs,to_srs)
print transf.TransformPoint(x1,y1)[:2]
(-179.99998854118684, 85.05112976833757)
# with the x,y coordinates of point y
print transf.TransformPoint(x2,y2)[:2]
(-13.178719028497795, 61.000416666720845)
```

If you want to use lists of coordinates:

```
x =  (-20037507.0672,-1467048.29156)
y =  (20037509.6184, 8625918.8737)
for i,j in zip(x,y):
   print transform(inProj,outProj,i, j)
(-179.99998854118687, 85.08398750388278)
(-13.178719028497799, 61.16289280460126)
```