# Pyproj transform returning incorrect values (EPSG 3875 to EPSG 4326)

Tags: python, pyproj

I am trying to convert from EPSG 3875 to EPSG 4326 and have this code:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

def convert_coordinates(input_format, output_format, x, y):

    input_format = "+init=epsg:" +str(input_format)
    output_format = "+init=epsg:" +str(output_format)

    inProj = Proj(input_format)
    outProj = Proj(output_format)

    return transform(inProj,outProj,x,y)

x, y = 4152144, 219039
x2,y2 = convert_coordinates("3875", "4326", x, y)
print x2, y2
```

This returns **112.264404642 154.392043378** which is out of bounds for EPSG 4326. But [ArcGIS](http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=3857&outSR=4326&geometries=%7B%0D%0A%22geometryType%22%20%3A%20%22esriGeometryPoint%22%2C%0D%0A%22geometries%22%20%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%7B%22x%22%20%3A%204152144%2C%20%22y%22%20%3A%20219039%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%7D&f=HTML) returns **37.2993441706517, 1.96727415792103** which is in bounds and looks better.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this code?

Comment: perhaps double check the epsg codes. You could also try this syntax: Proj(init="epsg:3875")

Comment: Swap your x and y values. AKA I think pyproj wants x = easting and y = northing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct procedure is

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj  = Proj("+init=EPSG:3857"))
outProj = Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")
x, y = 4152144, 219039
print transform(inProj,outProj,x,y)
(37.29934417065166, 1.96727415792103)
```

Your error is `convert_coordinates("3875", "4326", x, y)`: 3875 and 4326 are simple strings and not PyProj projections

Look at [pyProj Coordinate Transformation Incorrect](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141084/pyproj-coordinate-transformation-incorrect/141119#141119)

Comment: Awesome answer! That fixed it.